# Does twilio have message scheduling feature

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-functions

I want to schedule message according to week days using twilio dashboard or any api.

And Does twilio have message scheduling feature?

Comment: This question is probably best answered using the Twilio Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Twilio documentation you will see a use case for reminders here: [Twilio Use Cases](https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/contact-center/appointment-reminders/build). Note that the scheduling must be done on your application not within Twilio, as Twilio is a messaging provider only.